# Unable to make two way view with 2 rows

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am using [LucasR TwoWayView](https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view/). I want the View to have 2 rows and multiple columns.

[image]

Like the 4th Image in this picture except with 2 rows instead of 3. I tried many things but no use.

Here is my Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/categoryItems"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <org.lucasr.twowayview.TwoWayView
            android:id="@+id/filterGrid"
            style="@style/TwoWayView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_small"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
            app:twowayview_numRows="3"
            app:twowayview_layoutManager="GridLayoutManager" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#d3d3d3" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the Gradle Compilation:

```
compile 'org.lucasr.twowayview:twowayview:0.1.4'
```

But its not at all displaying 2 rows. Instead coming one single row with all the items. Please help.

Comment: Maybe you should consider creating the interface without that library.

Comment: You should post your twowayview style and the code where you set the adapter and such. and from what i can just see here, you set 3 ```app:twowayview_numRows="3"```

Comment: Actually that style contains nothing. Its there by mistake. I have already removed it. And adapter same as gridview.

Comment: change app:twowayview_numRows="3" to app:twowayview_numRows="2" and put the TwoWayView in parent of the xml, I mean don't put it inside any layout and see if it changes or not.

Comment: use a default gridview my friend and customise it

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/categoryItems"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <org.lucasr.twowayview.TwoWayView
            android:id="@+id/filterGrid"
            style="@style/TwoWayView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_small"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
            app:twowayview_numRows="3"
            app:twowayview_layoutManager="GridLayoutManager" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#d3d3d3" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Use Horizontal orientation for inner `LinearLayout`